# How can I develop my algorithm to converge in 1 so I can plot my neural network?

Tags: r, machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network

I tried to predict bankruptcy using the following part:

```
library(nnet)
library(neuralnet)
bank.nnet <- nnet(Bankrupt ~ .,data = test.set, size = 1, maxit = 500, type='class')
prob.nnet = predict(bank.nnet, test.set)
pred.nnet = as.numeric(prob.nnet > 0.06)

table(test.set$Bankrupt, pred.nnet, dnn = c("Observation", "Prediction"))
mean(ifelse(test.set$Bankrupt != pred.nnet, 1, 0))

n=6
bank.nnet.tune <- nnet(Bankrupt ~ ., 
                       size = n, data = train.set, maxit=1000, decay=0.006, linout = TRUE)   
prob.nnet.tune.train = predict(bank.nnet.tune, train.set)
pred.nnet.tune.train = as.numeric(prob.nnet.tune.train > 0.06)
#table(bank.test$DLRSN, pred.nnet.tune.train, dnn = c("Observation", "Prediction"))
table(train.set$Bankrupt, pred.nnet.tune.train, dnn = c("Observation", "Prediction"))
mean(ifelse(train.set$Bankrupt != pred.nnet.tune.train, 1, 0))

#outofsample
prob.nnet.tune = predict(bank.nnet.tune, train.set)
pred.nnet.tune = as.numeric(prob.nnet.tune > 0.06)
table(train.set$Bankrupt, pred.nnet.tune, dnn = c("Observation", "Prediction"))
mean(ifelse(train.set$Bankrupt != pred.nnet.tune, 1, 0))

library(verification)
data$Bankrupt=as.factor(data$Bankrupt)
#roc.plot(bank.test$DLRSN == "1", pred.nnet.tune)

nn <- neuralnet(Bankrupt ~ X1+X2+X3+X4+X5+X6+X7+X8+X9+X10,
                data=train.set,hidden=c(8,1),linear.output=T) 
plot(nn)
```

Now when I try to run the last line, I get the Warning message:

```
Warning message:
Algorithm did not converge in 1 of 1 repetition(s) within the stepmax.
```

And an Error message:

```
Error in plot.nn(nn) : weights were not calculated
```

I tried to set the linear.output to FALSE, which did not solve the problem.

Comment: There is not any *programming* issue here; your model did not converge, so it's only natural that the `plot` will not work. Why your model did not converge is not a programming question, please see the intro and NOTE in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info for more

Comment: You have set your parameters to restrict calculation within a programming context where those restrictions don’t really make sense. You should try to understand what each of your arguments do.  AND… you should explain what problem is being addressed. Just posting failed code cannot be accept as an explanation.